# Import .csv format file into openproject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After setting up the apache server When we choose the .csv file to be imported I get the following error message:

TypeError in `ProductImportsController#create`:

```
no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String
```

My `product_imports_controller.rb`:

```
require 'csv'    
class ProductImportsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product_import = ProductImport.new
  end

  def create
    csv_text = File.read(params[:product_import])
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
      ProductImport.create!(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you share the params, that you are getting in log?

Comment: Could you share the backtrace/ log?

Comment: TypeError (no implicit conversion of ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess into String):
  app/controllers/product_imports_controller.rb:8:in `read'
  app/controllers/product_imports_controller.rb:8:in `create'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
The issue is that there is a security aspect with hashes in Controllers.
You try `row.to_hash.permit!` but i'll doubt that it will work

Create it in the model:

```
require 'csv'    
class ProductImportsController < ApplicationController
  def new


 @product_import = ProductImport.new
  end

  def create
    csv_text = File.read(params[:product_import])
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
    csv.each do |row|
      ProductImport.create_from_csv(row.to_hash)
    end
  end

end


class ProductImport < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.create_from_csv(data)
     self.create!(data)
  end   
end
```